# Use one workspace for all pipeline jobs

Tags: jenkins

Подскажите кто знает. Как заставить пайплайн работать в одном воркспейсе (к примеру: /home/jenkins/workspace/pipeline), а не каждая джоба в своем? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, все просто, только надо быть внимательным :) Есть вкладка свернутая "Advanced Project Options" -> кликаем "Advanced" -> указываем в джобах "Use custom workspace" -> "Directory" = "workspace/pipeline". Таким образом джобы пайплайна отработают в одном воркспейсе.